# How do I append read_some buffer?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have some client asio code that uses `read_some()` until the number of bytes has been read.  But from looking at all the examples, I can't figure out how to assemble the read buffer into a larger one that contains the entire message.  How do I do this?

```
boost::array<char, 4096> buf;
while (lnTotalBytesRead < BigMessageSize)
{
    size_t len = obj->socket_.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
    lnTotalBytesRead += len;
    // Need to append each received block into large block.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, but can anyone answer the specific question about how to append buffers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't figure out how to assemble the read buffer into a larger one
>   that contains the entire message. How do I do this?

Use a [`streambuf`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/streambuf.html) instead of a `boost::array` for your buffer. Though, as [Andy said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7895894/how-do-i-append-read-some-buffer/7896074#7896074) you really should be using [`read()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_470/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload1.html). As the documentation states, it is a composed operation and handles invoking `read_some()` for you.

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the
>   stream's read_some function.

Answer (score 2):

Don't `read_some`, read the whole buffer at once by [read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload2.html):

```
boost::array<char, BigMessageSize> buf;
boost::asio::read(obj->socket_, boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);
```

Comment: the only reason to use read_some is if the buffer might be big enough that it might block for a non-trivial amount of time waiting for the rest

Answer (score 0):

Andy's answer seems to me the recommended approach if you aren't really expecting messages to be too long

Usually you'll have to append your message until you have a unit of work upon which you can proceed to do something - this hints strongly that you need some marker structure in your messages (headers, body, etc.) so you can isolate individual messages from it.

The simplest marker structure you can do is a 4-byte word at the start of the each message stating the length of the message. Then you'll have to append with `read_some` and check when the message full length has been received before dispatching it to further processing